# Are $\varphi$ and $\varphi^3$ the only powers of $\varphi$ that are also metallic ratios?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Given the sequence generator function: $$F_\lambda(n+2)=\lambda F_\lambda(n+1)+F_\lambda(n);\quad F_\lambda(0)=0, F_\lambda(1)=1$$ where $\lambda=1$ corresponds to the Fibonacci sequence, $\lambda=2$ corresponds to the Pell numbers, and so on, is it possible to generate a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \varphi^c=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a+b}{a}$ where $b=F_\lambda(n),\; a=F_\lambda(n+1),\,$ $\lambda \not\in \{1,4\}$, and $c \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I suppose that you had a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_mean .I do not know how much this could help but these are very interesting sequences for sure.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think you found the explanation. I put an answer.

Comment: $[ c\in \Bbb N \land  \psi^c=a/b=(a+b)/a]\implies$  $(a/b)^2=(a/b)+1$ $\implies a/b\in \{\psi,-\psi ^{-1}\}\implies$ $ c=1.$

Comment: I think what you meant was $ \lim_{n\to \infty}F_{\lambda}(n+1)/F_{\lambda}(n)=\psi^c.$

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, thank you @DanielWainfleet, where $\psi$ is the golden ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Claude's comment, I suspect you are asking for the values of $w$ in
$$ w^2 - 5 v^2 = -4. $$
These are [every other Lucas number,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) beginning with $w_1 = 1$ and $w_2 = 4,$ then continuing with $$w_{k+2} = 3 w_{k+1} - w_k$$ For example, with $w_3 = 11,$ the metallic number is
$$ \frac{11 + \sqrt{125}}{2} =  \frac{11 + 5 \sqrt{5}}{2} = \left(  \frac{1 +  \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^5$$
$$  $$
With $w_4 = 29,$ the metallic number is
$$ \frac{29 + \sqrt{845}}{2} =  \frac{29 + 13 \sqrt{5}}{2} = \left(  \frac{1 +  \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^7$$
$$ $$

```
w:  1  v:  1  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  4  v:  2  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  11  v:  5  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -1 ,  1
w:  29  v:  13
w:  76  v:  34
w:  199  v:  89
w:  521  v:  233
w:  1364  v:  610
w:  3571  v:  1597
w:  9349  v:  4181
w:  24476  v:  10946
w:  64079  v:  28657
w:  167761  v:  75025
w:  439204  v:  196418
w:  1149851  v:  514229
w:  3010349  v:  1346269
w:  7881196  v:  3524578
w:  20633239  v:  9227465
```

Comment: This is really nice !Thanks for posting this answer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity : how did you make the calculations ? Pari/GP ?

Comment: So $w$ is the Lucas number, and $v$ is the corresponding Fibonacci number, well done!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks. I mostly program in C++ with GMP. About 1995 they let me audit a course on C++ and graded my homework, so I feel pretty comfortable with it. After starting on this website, I have written quite a variety of programs on binary quadratic forms, with an emphasis on describing all solutions to $a x^2 + b xy + c y^2 = T,$ when the form is indefinite.